# Override NestJS Service outside of tests

Tags: nestjs

I have this code:

```
import { Module, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService {
  constructor() {
    console.log('init original')
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class PrismaServiceMock {
  constructor() {
    console.log('init mock')
  }
}

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: PrismaService,
      useClass: PrismaService,
    },
  ],
  exports: [PrismaService],
})
export class PrismaModule {}

@Module({
  imports: [PrismaModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: PrismaService,
      useClass: PrismaServiceMock,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Because of

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: PrismaService,
      useClass: PrismaServiceMock,
    },
  ],
```

I expect `PrismaServiceMock` to be instantiated. However, both `PrismaService` are still created. What do I miss?

Comment: I'm trying to follow the documentation here https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#value-providers-usevalue

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
                        providers: [
                                        {
                                            provide: PrismaService,
                                            useValue: {
                                                    onModuleInit: jest.fn()
                                            },
                                        },
                                    ]
});
```

or mock your database driver:

```
jest.mock('mysql')
```

or:

```
jest.spyOn(mysql,'connect').mockImplemetation()
```

or in the case of MongoDB, do something like:

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
                        providers: [
                            { provide: 'DatabaseConnection', useValue: {} }
                        ]
});
```

Comment: that is true. can I do it not in a testing context?

Comment: Oh, I didn't pay attention to the title carefully, sorry. I think its a sign that you are doing something wrong, you shouldn't be ever in a situation to mock something in your operating code outside testing! why don't you separate your code into two services one with the database and one without? Or you can check your conditions and then connect to the database if needed!

Comment: we use GraphQL and want to generate schema without having to connect to the DB. ideally, I'd run the app with providing a different DB service that does nothing